# Redirection of error into a file using ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, redirect, stderr, processbuilder

I am trying to redirect error messages produced by GCC compiler into a file
during the compilation of a C program using ProcessBuilder. Code is like this

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder1 = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/gcc",
"-o"+"/home/hipad/hipad/UserProject/example","/home/hipad/hipad/UserProject/example.c
2>/home/hipad/hipad/UserProject/example.gccmessages");

processBuilder1.start();
```

But this is giving error.The error is

```
"/usr/bin/gcc,-o/home/hipad/hipad/UserProject/example,/home/hipad/hipad/UserProj‌​ect/example.c 2>/home/hipad/hipad/UserProject/example.gccmessages": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Can anybody suggest the way to do it?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: @Lakshmi_ java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/gcc,-o/home/hipad/hipad/UserProject/example,/home/hipad/hipad/UserProject/example.c  2>/home/hipad/hipad/UserProject/example.gccmessages": error=2, No such file or directory

Comment: check if example.gccmessages actually exists in that path.

Comment: The code (exactly as shown) would not actually compile cleanly.  1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and (continue to) build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command-line redirection is a feature provided by the shell that you're using (bash, sh, csh, etc). Your `ProcessBuilder` is launching `gcc` directly, without using a shell. So shell features like redirection and piping aren't available.

There are two solutions. First of all, The Java 7 version of `ProcessBuilder` adds functions to redirect the standard I/O channels for the child processes. If you're using Java 7, this should work:

```
ProcessBuilder pb1 = new ProcessBuilder(
    "/usr/bin/gcc",
    "-o",
    "/home/hipad/hipad/UserProject/example",
    "/home/hipad/hipad/UserProject/example.c");
pb1.redirectError(new File("/home/hipad/hipad/UserProject/example.gccmessages"));
```

If you're not using Java 7 or don't wnat to do this, you can run a shell and have it run gcc for you. This method gives you full access to the shell's command-line parsing features:

```
ProcessBuilder pb1 = new ProcessBuilder(
    "sh",
    "-c",
    "gcc -o /home/hipad/hipad/UserProject/example /home/hipad/hipad/UserProject/example.c 2> /home/hipad/hipad/UserProject/example.gccmessages");
```

In this case, the final argument could be anything you can type at an `sh` command line.